# Mqtt: How to install mosquitto old version

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have installed mosquitto using the command `apt-get install mosquitto`. It is installed successfully on my system, but I got version "1.4.5". I want to downgrade to version 1.4.4, so I was trying using the source tar file. Under folder, I am running the command `make` and it is throwing an error:

```
set -e; for d in lib client src; do make -C ${d}; done
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/org.eclipse.mosquitto-1.4.4/lib'
cc -Wall -ggdb -O2  -I. -I.. -I../lib -fPIC -DWITH_TLS -DWITH_TLS_PSK -DWITH_THREADING -DWITH_SOCKS -DWITH_SRV -c mosquitto.c -o mosquitto.o
In file included from mosquitto.c:33:0:
./mosquitto_internal.h:27:27: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <openssl/ssl.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [mosquitto.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/org.eclipse.mosquitto-1.4.4/lib'
make: *** [mosquitto] Error 2
```

What is going wrong here?. Is there any another way to install 1.4.4 version of mosquitto?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to go back to 1.4.4?

Comment: The error is that you do not have the openssl development package installed, apt-get install libssl-dev will likely solve this problem

Comment: We are facing some issues in 1.4.5. on 1.4.5,some messages are not going to deliver,when i was on 1.4.4,it was working fine. so for make sure,i want to test on 1.4.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing dependencies needed for compilation.

Try:

```
apt-get install libc-ares-dev libssl-dev libwrap0-dev uthash-dev uuid-dev
```

If you want libwebsockets support you can either install libwebsockets-dev, or better install it manually from source - that will get you version 1.5 instead of the old 1.2 that is in Debian/Ubuntu.

If you install the manually compiled version with

```
make prefix=/usr install
```

then it will overwrite the existing binary and you can use it with the existing system services.

Comment: yes,it is working fine,but how can i use mosquitto as service.now i am starting mosquitto under folder ?

Comment: yes,when i am going to start sudo service mosquitto start,it is showing me "mosquitto start/running, process 16445".but it is not going to start,what is the issue ?

Comment: You'll have to do some debugging yourself I'm afraid. Is the old process still running perhaps?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but your answer helped me install Mosquitto. :) However, `make prefix=/usr install` did not work. It complained that it can't find `install` command.